# How to animate a div only if it's at a specific position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to animate (slide down) a `div`; for example, if it's **only** at a certain position on the page?

For example, there are four divs that all have the same class `.ALLCONTENT`, but when a button (which has class `.BUTTONS`) is clicked only the div that's at 30 px from the top will animate downwards, the rest will remain in the same place.

Basically, slide down a div to a certain position, if that div's in that position already it wont slide further down; the problem I'm having now with

```
$(".BUTTONS").click(function(){
    $(".ALLCONTENT").animate({"top":"+=558px"}, 250, 'linear');
});
```

Comment: Why can't the divs have different IDs?

Comment: can you put the code in jsfiddler http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
if($(".ALLCONTENT").offset().top === 20) {
    //Do something
}
```

if you want check its absolute position to the document / body

and

```
if($(".ALLCONTENT").css("top") === "20px") {
    //Do something
}
```

or

```
if($(".ALLCONTENT").position().top === 20) {
    //Do something
}
```

if you want check its relative position

Comment: any reason you need the triple equals in the first and last code samples?

Comment: no you could also use double equals... I am just used to strict comparison as it is a little bit faster

Comment: strict comparison also ensures that the type is equal so `20 == "20" // true` but `20 === "20" // false`

Answer (score 0):

If it is not possible to assign id's (even though I can not image that), use this:

```
if($(".ALLCONTENT").css("top") == "20px") {
//Do something

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".BUTTONS").click(function(){  
    $(".ALLCONTENT").each(function(i){
        if($(this).css("top")=="30px"){
            $(this).animate({"top":"558px"}, 250, "linear");
        }
    })
});
```